# Sorting multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

Good evening. I am looking to see if it is possible to sort multiple columns in excel by selecting a value in Column A's filter.

Meaning: When I select Automobile in the drop down filter, Column B would show Cash and Column C would show paid.

What are the steps I would need to take in accomplishing this task.

**Column A values**:
House Payment
Automobile Payment
**Column B Values**:
Check
Cash
Credit Card
No money
**Column C Values**:
Paid
Unpaid

Comment: Wrong site. General software use questions should be asked at [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are appropriate to ask here. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite While this question may be better suited for Super Users, this site is not just for "programming questions".  It is also for excel formulas.  There is even a tag for Excel, Excel -VBA, and Excel-Formulas

Comment: @ForwardEd: Yes, there are, for questions that ask about Excel VBA, or Excel formulas. -There are also many tags here that are now off-topic as other sites have been created. Existence of tags or previous questions are not relevant; what matters is current site guidelines at the time the question is asked. This is a basic software use question related to Excel.  The [help/on-topic] quite clearly explains the guidelines here. Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: Good morning. I assumed vb script/vba questions were related to programming. Delete this question, I asked on super users.

Comment: VBA/VBA Script questions *are* related to programming. Unfortunately, you've not asked about either of them.